# Изменение кнопок ToollBar

Tags: objective-c

Доброго времени суток. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему. Есть приложение для распознавания QR-кодов, распознавание реализовано с помощью библиотеке ZBar. При сканировании вызывается modalViewController:

```
// Создаем объект, получающий картинку с камеры
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;
ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
/*
 Мы будем считывать только QR-коды. Для этого мы сперва отключим распознавание всех поддерживаемых библиотекой штрих-кодов…
 */
[scanner setSymbology:0 config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:0];
/*
 … а затем включим распознавание QR-кодов:
 */
[scanner setSymbology:ZBAR_QRCODE config:ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to:1];
reader.readerView.zoom = 1.0;

reader.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
 /*
 Далее показываем пользователю в модальном режиме представление (форму), сканирующую QR-код:
 */

[self presentModalViewController:reader animated:YES];
```

В этом окне внизу отображен toolBar с двумя кнопками "back" и "i", нужно изменить внешний вид кнопки "back", а кнопку "i" скрыть.

P.S. Пробовал просто скрыть toolBar

```
 reader.navigationController.toolbar.hidden = YES;
```

ничего не происходит. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так делаю.

P.P.S Получилось скрыть ToolBar, теперь не знаю как добавить новый

```
[reader setShowsZBarControls: NO];
```

Comment: @Pavlyuk, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Помню точно что в Zbar основная библиотека уже скомпилирована, и кажется код который отвечает за отрисовку UI в том числе. Проверьте этот момент. От себя посоветую zxing - http://hashcode.ru/questions/177846/objective-c-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-qr-code-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-ios  тут обсуждали

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю примеры, если не разберусь с Zbar. Просто на Zbar уже все готово не охота переделывать.И как то же его переопределить можно.

Answer (score 1):

Создай новый класс, используя наследование от ZBarReaderViewController.
В методе didLoadView добавь свой subview. Замени

```
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new]
```

на свой новый класс.